# Storyboard elements are not sized properly on the device

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, storyboard

In the storyboard, I am placing a table view element into a subclassed UIView. The element is not appearing on the iPad device I am running it on the same as it appears in the storyboard however. This also happens for additional content that I place into the storyboard. Below is a screenshot as it appears in the storyboard, as well as UI width/height information.

[image: Correct UI]

And here is the description of the UI file running on the iPad.

https://gist.github.com/4323186 (embedding it directly into the post is giving me problems)

You'll notice that the tableview is explicitly set at 178 width, and is showing up in the description as 276 width. My initial thought was that perhaps a cell was forcing the parent to be larger (I'm very new to iOS UI development), but drilling into that shows the prototype cell it appears that the width is defined by it's parent at 178. The image views and label also are appearing in the incorrect spot, as shown in the second image below.

[image: Error UI on iPad]

Comment: Can you post some code on how are you populating the UITableView? To test in the number of sections set it to 1, number of rows return more than 1 and on the uitableviewcell set the cell.textlabel.text to [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d",indexPath.row] that will generate some info in the tableview.

Comment: @nizx I know that the example screenshot shows that all empty, the data is lazily loaded from a model. I didn't see any reason to load it up for the screenshot. That all works just fine, I don't think any part of that code controls sizing, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off all of those Autosizing constraints in the inspector panel for all the rogue views, and carefully adding back the ones you need. With all the constraints on, as in your first screenshot, any change in the parent view's `bounds` could make those subviews unexpectedly try to readjust.

Comment: Turning off the autosizing constraints helped a lot, views appear properly. As I said above, I'm really new to UI development, thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: No problem! If you're not under any sort of time constraint for learning iOS, it may be worth it to go through the Stanford iOS course on iTunes U. Even if you don't watch every one sequentially, it helps to use the relevant lectures as an overview before you venture into a new part of iOS development. Cheers!